# Ground noise while using multiple switching regulators

Tags: power-supply

Is there any important points to consider especially about noise when more than one switching regulator is connected into the same ground reference or having a separate ground layer in the pcb is good enough ?

To summarize, is there any extra precautions to take while dealing with multiple switching regulators or designing them one by one as if they were the only one would be fine when it comes to dealing with noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do it is to keep the ground plane under each supply separate up to one point nearest the connector that is bringing the power into the device.  You can then connect the separate ground planes there, at that single point. This helps keep the signals from radiating into other ground "islands".

Answer (score 1):

Ideally when working with switching mode power supplies, you'd want at least four layers so you can physically isolate the power-stage from the signal-stage.

Regardless of how many layers you have though, it is quite considerable to make sure that you connect all of your small-signal ground connections together on the signal layer and then drop the ground connection to your ground plane through a single via.

This will reduce the amount of noise that is injected into your ground plane.

Answer (score -1):

with any power supply (I am assuming that what you're speaking about is a switch-mode power supply) at least one decoupling cap should be used to isolate the power supply from the rest of you circuit. Also, it wouldn't hurt to up-rate the cap inside the power supply you are designing to account for a bit more ripple.